# Save Shell Command Output in a Variable and Use it across Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: bash, docker, shell, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, amazon-ecr

How could I store the output of a shell command in which I am returning the latest docker image name? After this stage, I need the same name(variable) in the next stage where I should pass this variable as a parameter?

I tried the below code:

```
    stage('LATEST') {
        steps {
            script{
                LATEST_IMAGE= sh (
                returnStdout: true,
                script: "docker images | awk '{print $1}' | awk 'NR==2'"
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to store the above shell script output in the LATEST_IMAGE variable and use it in the next stage where I am pushing the Image to ECR. With this piece of pipeline code I am getting the below error:

**Error Details:**

*WorkflowScript: 54: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 54, column 103.
"docker images | awk '{print $1}' | awk*

**P.S -** The above command works fine though when run from the terminal.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `either escape a literal dollar sign "$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}"` so did you try it?

Comment: Got this output after using awk print {1}:+ docker images
+ awk print 1
+ awk NR==2
awk: cmd. line:1: print
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error